# Counting each unique array of an array in each row of a column in a data frame

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, unique

I am practicing pandas and python and I am not so good at for loops. I have a data frame as below: let's say this is df:

```
   Name        Value
    A      [[A,B],[C,D]]   
    B      [[A,B],[D,E]] 
    C      [[D,E],[K,L],[M,L]] 
    D      [[K,L]]
```

I want to go through each row and find unique arrays and count them.

I have tried np.unique(a, return_index=True) then returns two different list and my problem I don't know how to go through each array.

Expected result would be:

```
Value      Counts
[A,B]        2
[D,E]        2
[K,L]        2
[C,D]        1
[M,L]        1
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) with [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = df['Value'].explode().value_counts().rename_axis('Value').reset_index(name='Counts')
print (df)
    Value  Counts
0  [D, E]       2
1  [A, B]       2
2  [K, L]       2
3  [C, D]       1
4  [M, L]       1
```

Numpy solution:

```
a, v = np.unique(np.concatenate(df['Value']),axis=0, return_counts=True)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Value':a.tolist(), 'Counts':v})
print (df)
    Value  Counts
0  [A, B]       2
1  [C, D]       1
2  [D, E]       2
3  [K, L]       2
4  [M, L]       1
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know explode() method for series.

Comment: @beginner - ya, I think `Series.explode` is better here, `DataFrame.explode` is used if need duplicated another columns - check `print (df.explode('Value'))`

Answer (score 6):

Use  [DataFrame.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) in pandas +0.25:

```
df.explode('Value')['Value'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
[K, L]    2
[A, B]    2
[D, E]    2
[C, D]    1
[M, L]    1
Name: Value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Please not copy solution

Comment: What do you mean by not copy solution?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know explode() method.

Comment: I wanted to propose additionally the method proposed by jezrael. Example to make my solution more complete. Jezrael prevented me from doing it

Comment: I am glad to help you:)

Comment: Thanks, the both solutions work as charm. I chose the other solution, it is shorter for my use :) Have a nice day!